# Driving an RFID device from a presumably noisy boost step-up converter

Tags: noise, step-up

I'm building a circuit that will be powered by six AA batteries producing 9V at full charge.  Part of the circuit powers an RFID device that works at 9V and probably somewhat less than that.  I'd like to keep it working all the way to the point where the battery pack voltage has fallen to about 4V or so at which point other parts of circuit operating at 3.3V would be approaching failure.  The RFID device is an implant transponder (134.2kHz) whose range is reduced by the presence of line noise, which consumes 150mA at 9V and will need to continuously operate for a period of about 5 seconds or so.  To get 9V from 4V will require a step-up boost converter, which is bound to be noisy.  I'm wondering if charging up a large capacitor, turning off the converter and driving the RFID from the quiet battery for those 5 seconds would be a viable strategy and if anyone has any recommendations for doing so.  Thanks.

Comment: using dV/dT = I / C. assume your 9 volts is allowed to droop to 8 volts, in 5 seconds. Thus dV/dT = 1/5. The "I" is 0.15. What is the C? you need about one farad.

Comment: You better come up with better specs for voltage, energy and spectral noise tolerance from DC to say 2MHz ,  to find a solution.

Comment: Actually, it appears to be a little less dramatic than that, analog, although it still may be unrealistic.  9V driving 150mA implies an R of 60 ohms.  Of course, I'd want to go over voltage somewhat and regulate down to 9 to maintain 9.  A quick calculation of stepping up to 18V and a 10,000uF capacitor (which costs as little as $1.46 on Mouser) produces 180mA at t=0, 147.4mA at t=2 and 109mA at t=5 without regulation.  With regulation, the rate of voltage decay should be reduced such that I might be able to maintain 150mA through t=5, though I should compute the regulated rate of  decay.

Comment: BTW, are there other other economical options for charge storage in that ballpark?

Comment: Sunny, you appear to suggesting that I'm planning to run directly from the step-up converter.  Since a battery would be the cleanest quietest possible power source with a linear regulator, I'm proceeding on that premise, preferring to not dive into spectral anything and just go for simple best performance instead.  Implying AC mutual induction to power the tag, radio signal transmission from tag and radio reception by a receiver, spectral anything would get pretty complex and best be avoided.

Comment: Oops.  Damn.  Make that more like 100,000uF.  Now, that's a horse of a different price.  More like $9 min for 16V.  Now it's starting to hurt.